# Pushing down content on .slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm having some trouble when designing a responsive layout as follows below:

If you browse to http://www.wickersleysixthform.net you can see this in action.

Basically I'm trying to create a responsive menu so in browsers of 768px and above you will see a normal horizontal navigation. Then for anything under 481px you will see the "three line" menu with a .slideToggle() effect on that once pressed drops down the menu.

I can sort of get this to work, but the .slideToggle() isn't pushing the rest of the content down which I need it to do. Also the three lines won't appear if I re-size my browser screen manually however if I resize then refresh the page it will do, but if I do that then the normal links in the larger screen size don't show. I hope that makes sense.

This is the jQuery I'm using for the toggle inside a jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});

```
/* getting viewport width */
var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();

/* if is below 481px */
if (responsive_viewport < 481) {

    $(".top-nav").before('<div id="menu">&#9776;</div>');
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $(".top-nav").slideToggle();
    });

}

/* if is above or equal to 768px */
if (responsive_viewport >= 768) {

    $(".top-nav").show();
}
```

Can anyone help? No doubt it's something simple but it's driving me insane. Possibly CSS based rather than the jQuery?

The CSS I'm using is as follows (in my base/mobile stylesheet).

```
.header {
background-color:@blue;
padding-top:10px;
height:50px;
}

#menu {
display:block;
font-size:1.75em;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 2px;
}

.top-nav {
display:none;
}

.top-nav.open {
display:block;
background:@blue;
}
```

In my 768 and up stylesheet:

```
.header {
padding-top:0;
height:70px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
z-index:10;
}

#menu {
display:none;
}

.top-nav {
display:block;
}
```

My HTML structure:

```
<header class="header" role="banner">
<div id="inner-header" class="wrap clearfix">
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net">
<img id="logo" width="50px" height="36px" src="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/wp-content/themes/sixthform/library/images/white.png">
</a>
<nav role="navigation">
<div id="menu">☰</div>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav top-nav clearfix">
<li><a href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/">About</a></li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/current/">Current Students</a>
<ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/courses/">Courses</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/student-life/">Student Life</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Prospectus</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/apply/">Apply</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.wickersleysixthform.net/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: most likely the element being slid down isn't in the normal document flow. We'd need to see css and html.

Comment: @KevinB - I think it would be easier to look at the site for that rather than me show it which is why I didn't include it. I can post it up instead though if that will help?

Comment: @EnigmaRM - In the UK students are graded A - E and also A* - C and A* - C (including Maths & English), the schools/sixth forms then work this in to their stats!

Comment: It might be easier, but it's useless to the community. Once you fix your problem, the link to your site won't show the problem anymore and there won't be any code to reproduce it. Also, without said information your question could be considered Off-Topic and closed.

Comment: Best would be to include a small subsection of your code that re-produces the problem you are having.

Comment: @KevinB no problem - I'm new to posting here so wasn't sure. I've posted up some of the CSS and HTML structure, hopefully that helps? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The menu is positioned absolutely, therefore it is out of the document flow. When it's height changes, it simply overlays the elements it is positioned over. If you want it to push the elements down, you'll have to instead position it relatively.

Comment: No, the menu isn't absolutely positioned, only the icon is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `header` element has a fixed height of 50px. So when the menu expands the header stays the same height.

Removing the height or replacing it with `min-height` solves your problem

Comment: Thank you! I've replaced it with min-height and that works. Any ideas on why I'm losing the menu or the menu icon not showing on resizing the browser window?

Comment: Because the `#menu` element is added with javascript and only on page load. (scripts.js:34) Why don't you always add the menu item in your HTML and simply hide it with media queries?